# Issue with C# sonarqube plugin

Tags: tfs, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a SonarQube 5.6 installed since a year now, It's integrated with TFS. Installed with few additional plugins, C#, dependency-check, fxcop, java, Checkmarx, scm-cvs, scm-git, scm-svn and scm-tfvc. 
everything was working fine. Today it's started failing build with error
`2017-06-26T17:54:22.7387533Z Downloading SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip from http://xxxxxxx:9000/static/csharp/SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip to E:\agnt\_work\41\.sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip
2017-06-26T17:54:22.7397520Z ##[error]Could not find a file on the SonarQube server. Url: http://xxxxxxxxxx:9000/static/csharp/SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip
2017-06-26T17:54:22.7407523Z ##[error]Failed to update the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild binaries. Check the server url, verify that the C# plugin is correctly installed on the SonarQube server and that the SonarQube server has been restarted.
2017-06-26T17:54:22.7417526Z ##[error]Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1
2017-06-26T17:54:22.8678238Z ##[error]System.Exception: Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1
2017-06-26T17:54:22.8698250Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.InvokeBatchScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2017-06-26T17:54:22.8708248Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()`

From the error, I can it's something related to C# plugin. I checked that plugin  under /extensions/plugins and it's there. I thought it can be something compatibility issue, I tried to upgrade it to latest one 6.0

After installing 6.0 tried again and got the same error.

I also tried with old version of same plugins. tried 5.3, 5.0. After manually copied jar file under /plugins. Tried to restart the sonar server and it didn't started successfully. I got the error as below,

`2017.06.26 18:31:11 ERROR web[o.s.s.p.Platform] Fail to stop server - ignored
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot stop.  Current container state was: CONSTRUCTED at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleState.stopping(DefaultLifecycleState.java:72) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na] at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stop(DefaultPicoContainer.java:794) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
2017.06.26 18:31:11 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to load plugin FxCop [fxcop] at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerExtensionInstaller.installExtensions(ServerExtensionInstaller.java:74) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na] at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel4.start(PlatformLevel4.java:691) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na] at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:216) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to register extension org.sonar.api.config.PropertyDefinition at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.addExtension(ComponentContainer.java:248) ~[sonar-core-5.6.jar:na] at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerExtensionInstaller.installExtension(ServerExtensionInstaller.java:111) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na] at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerExtensionInstaller.installExtensions(ServerExtensionInstaller.java:66) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
Caused by: org.picocontainer.PicoCompositionException: Duplicate Keys not allowed. Duplicate for 'org.sonar.api.config.PropertyDefinition-sonar.cs.fxcop.timeoutMinutes'at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterInternal(DefaultPicoContainer.java:438) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
2017.06.26 18:31:11 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file 2017.06.26 18:31:11 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2017.06.26 18:31:11 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread
2017.06.26 18:31:11 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:47) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105) ~[sonar-process-5.6.jar:na]at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:68) [sonar-server5.6.jar:na]`

can someone please help to fix this issue?

Comment: Try to restart the server without the FxCop plugin. Do you have a database backup?  Restore the backup could be the last resort.

Comment: I uninstalled fxcop plugin and restarted server. still same error during build. I don't have a database backup. Also, why it's giving an error for C# plugin during the build.

Comment: @JeroenHeier - Thank you. I got it working. Not C# latest version but i got it working 5.0 version of C# plugin after uninstalling FxCop plugin. Thanks for comment.

Comment: You should try to update to at least to [C# 5.11](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441900)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by removing FxCop plugin. Somehow that plugin stopped working. can be the version what i was using that was not compatible with C# plugin. I installed C# plugin version 5.0 (latest is 6.0)

as mentioned above, if i want to use C# latest version, i need to update sonar scanner for MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the [Scanner for MsBuild](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/releases) as well. The old versions are not compatible with SonarC# 6+.